# display next page asynchronously and then run its page load event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an airline site in which i am trying to display the fare from different API/Web service.  But Firstly i want to display the search page--> Display processing --> binding data in the page from theses API/web service as they received.
          but i am not able to display search page before the result processing.
What i have tried (code)-

```
public partial class asyncgridview : System.Web.UI.Page,ICallbackEventHandler
 {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsCallback)
      {
         ltCallback.Text = ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "'bindgrid'", "EndGetData", "'asyncgrid'", false);      
      }
    }
   private string _Callback;
   public string GetCallbackResult()
   {
      return _Callback;
   }

 public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
 {
    DataTable table = fetchData();
    gvAsync.DataSource = table;
    gvAsync.DataBind();
    using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        gvAsync.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
        _Callback = sw.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

regards
Avishek

Comment: Please include more details, like what it does or doesn't do that you expect it to do, and be *specific*.

Comment: refer to www.bharatbrahaman.com or www.yatra.com .  how the result page is displayed after search button is clicked . The above code will load the result page first then callback the client event and thereafter as soon as the result is available it will display onto the gridview. Similarly i want to create a result page that will display the result from multiple API as soon as they are received by various task. Above is the sample code  ,what i have tried.